# Why is the Cartesian Product of a non-empty set and ∅ is resulted in ∅?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can we prove that A x ∅ = ∅, for any given set A?

For the Cartesian Product of non-empty sets, A and B,

A x B = {(a,b) : a ∈ A, b ∈ B}

But for the Cartesian Product of a non-empty set and an empty set, A and ∅,

A x ∅ = {(a,b) : a ∈ A, b ∈ ∅}

Since ∅ has no element, how can we write the conclusion for the proof?

Comment: Argue by contradiction. Suppose there is an $x \in A \times \emptyset$ and work from there. If you want more help, [edit] your post to include your understanding and attempts; this isn't a site where you expect the other users to do your work/homework for you.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: @PrincessEev I'm sorry for my absence in explanation about the part that I don't understand. I have now updated the question. Furthermore, I would like to thank you because I got the idea to prove with contradiction based on your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is by contradiction.

Assume for the sake of contradiction that $(a, x)$ is an element of $A \times \varnothing$.

Then, by the definition of the Cartesian product, $x \in \varnothing$.

But by the definition of the empty set, $\forall \, x, \, x \not \in \varnothing$.

Contradiction! Thus, our assumption must be wrong, and so $A \times \varnothing$ cannot contain any elements.

Answer (score 1):

For the Cartesian Product of non-empty sets, $A$ and $B$,

$A \times B = \{(a,b) : a \in A, b \in B\}$

But for the Cartesian Product of a non-empty set and an empty set, $A$ and $\emptyset$,
it has to be

$A \times \emptyset = \{(a,b) : a ∈ A, b ∈ \emptyset\}$

Since $\emptyset$ has no element, $b \notin \emptyset$.

Therefore, the contradiction is formed, completing the proof.